# Преобразование слов в математическое выражение

Tags: python

Мне необходимо перевести строку со словами на русском языке в математическое выражение. Пример "сто двадцать три умножить на 4 делить на 10" ---> "123 * 4 / 10". Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Из тупого, могу предложить разбить строку по пробелам и анализировать каждое слово.

Comment: @oleksandrigo это был один из вариантов, но я бы хотел сделать более элегантное решение

Comment: Сначала разбейте строку по действиям, потом что между действиями преобразуйте в числа, потом всё это обработайте. Вкратце так.

Answer (score 0):

Взято из поста вот тут: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493788/19820852). Единственное, тут работа с английским, но суть проблемы одна и та же.

```
def text2int(textnum, numwords={}):
    if not numwords:
      units = [
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight",
        "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen",
    "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen",
  ]

      tens = ["", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]

      scales = ["hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion"]

      numwords["and"] = (1, 0)
      for idx, word in enumerate(units):    numwords[word] = (1, idx)
      for idx, word in enumerate(tens):     numwords[word] = (1, idx * 10)
      for idx, word in enumerate(scales):   numwords[word] = (10 ** (idx * 3 or 2), 0)

    current = result = 0
    for word in textnum.split():
        if word not in numwords:
          raise Exception("Illegal word: " + word)

        scale, increment = numwords[word]
        current = current * scale + increment
        if scale > 100:
            result += current
            current = 0

    return result + current
print text2int("seven billion one hundred million thirty one thousand three hundred thirty seven")

#7100031337
```